# How to align ruby string to left or right?

Tags: ruby, string

I have few ruby strings, which I want to align left and right appropriately.

I'm now using `"Name".center(20, " ")` to get `"(7 spaces)Name(8 spaces)"`

How can I achieve `"Name(15 spaces)"` or `"(15 spaces)Name"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
"Name".ljust(19)
"Name".rjust(19)
```

Answer (score 8):

Ruby has a [`printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) method defined in `Kernel`, try using that.

It supports many common "`f`" ("format", like in `scanf`, `printf`, ...) options (see e.g. `man 3 printf`).

Left and right justification can be done like this (extracted from comment):

```
printf("%10s", "right")
printf("%-10s","left")
```

Comment: Theres no right justify there, only left - [source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

Comment: printf("%10s","string here") for right justify  printf("%-10s","string here") for left justify

Answer (score 1):

### Insert *n* Copies of a Character

There are certainly other ways to do this, but one of them is to use the splat operator to copy a character (e.g. the space character) a certain number of times. For example:

```
puts (' ' * 15) + 'Name'
puts 'Name' + (' ' * 15)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think sawa's solution is more elegant and readable.